# Shell_exec on echo outputs strange things

Tags: php

Hi don't know why when I'm outputing the result of the shell_exec, I have stuff like "[0;39m" and such, how I can remove this ?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your `shell_exec` command argument?

Comment: was just finnishing reading that this could be because of the colors ?!
It is a custom program, to automate some stuff of a server nothing from linux it self in sort of speak

Comment: Please show some of your code. How could we answer if you did not put enough details.

Comment: It was the coloers, found the awnser for it, will reply with it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding this to the variable

```
$cmd .= " | sed -r \"s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g\"";
```

It fixed the probem for me.

The problem was because of the colors of the output of the command on the linux that would make that strange stuff